# How can I make the white area transparent in this bottom navigation bar that I have implemented using stack in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

This is the code for the layout. I have built the layout using stack. A sizedbox with height 115 contains the stack which further contains the Row of icon buttons and the plus icon button. I have tried replacing the sizedbox with container and changing the color to transparent but to no avail. I don't really know from where the white area is being generated.

```
SizedBox(
      height: 115,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 75,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
              color: Color.fromRGBO(37, 37, 37, 1),
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: List.generate(
                5,
                (index) {
                  if (index == 2) {
                    return const SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      width: 40,
                    );
                  }
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => nextScreens[index],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          iconsUrl[index],
                          height: 20,
                          width: 20,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          titles[index],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SellPage(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 60,
                    width: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: primaryColor,
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white, width: 3),
                    ),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      size: 30,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "Sell",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the white must be from outside this code, because I copied it and I don't have the issue

Comment: @IvoBeckers you are correct. When I added the same widget to another page I didn't get the white region but I am still unable to understand why I am getting the white area in the homepage

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have added the SizedBox inside a column. So the widgets inside the column is rendered just above the SizedBox. Remove the SizedBox from here and add it above the column in a stack like

```dart
SizedBox(
height: Mediaquery.of(context).size.height,
width : Mediaquery.of(context).size.width,
child: Stack(
  children: [
    Column(),
    Positioned (
     bottom: 0,   
      child: SizedBox(),//bottom bar here
    )
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be it is because you have given height 115 to SizedBox

Comment: It is better if you could include tested code-snippet and which will solve the issue, More about [answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)